# How to pause a frame from loading in actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript, time-wait

I have a game in which a flight will shoot bullets and when the bullet hits an enemy ship a blast effect comes and another frame loads. Now the problem i'm facing with is the blast effect and the next frame are loading at a time. So, I've added this script:

```
if (this.hitTest(_root["enemy1"])) {
    this.removeMovieClip();
    _root.enemy1._x=2000;
    _root.option1._x=2000;
    addExplosion(800, 200, explosionParticleAmount, explosionDistance, explosionSize, explosionAlpha);
    this._x=-900000;
    var sound:Sound = new Sound(this);
    sound.attachSound("explode");
    sound.start();
    flag = true;
    wait();
    checkAnswer(_root.option1.text);
}

function wait() {
  stop();
  var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
      play();
      clearInterval(myInterval);
  }, 5*1000); // stop for 5 seconds
}

function checkAnswer(answer){
  if(questions[level][1] == answer){  
     status_flag=true;
     score=score+10;
     bullet_fire=false;
     gotoAndStop(3);
  }else{
      bullet_fire=false;
     gotoAndStop("Scene 2",1);
  }
}
```

But still the result is same. I also tried increasing the time, but i am still unable to stop that another frame from pausing. Please help me out. Thank you

Comment: Just as an aside; you should really consider upgrading to ActionScript 3.0 if at all possible and structure the code using classes rather than the timeline - it will make your life a whole lot easier ;)

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely look forward to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following should work for you, though a more robust method would be to pause until you receive an event to signal that your explosion animation has completed. The problem with the current method is that if you change the length of your explosion sequence, you need to remember to update the length of your pause also.

```
if (this.hitTest(_root["enemy1"])) {
    this.removeMovieClip();
    _root.enemy1._x=2000;
    _root.option1._x=2000;
    addExplosion(800, 200, explosionParticleAmount, explosionDistance, explosionSize, explosionAlpha);
    this._x=-900000;
    var sound:Sound = new Sound(this);
    sound.attachSound("explode");
    sound.start();
    flag = true;
    wait();
}

function wait() {
  stop();
  var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
      //play();
      checkAnswer(_root.option1.text); // check answer after explosion has finished
      clearInterval(myInterval);
  }, 5*1000); // stop for 5 seconds
}

function checkAnswer(answer){
  if(questions[level][1] == answer){  
     status_flag=true;
     score=score+10;
     bullet_fire=false;
     gotoAndStop(3);
  }else{
      bullet_fire=false;
     gotoAndStop("Scene 2",1);
  }
}
```